# GPIOZERO how to install lastest version on Ubuntu 20.10 servver

Tags: gpio, ubuntu, gpiozero

I am running gpiozero on my Raspberry Pi4 Ubuntu 20.10.

I need to update gpiozero (1.2) to latest version (1.6.1) to use the RotaryEncoder class which is not present in the package I have installed

The install tools (see below) show that there is no newer package.

On https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/python3-gpiozero there is a 1.6.1. for Ubuntu 21.04

any help is much appreciated.

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.10 aarch64 
Host: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4 
Kernel: 5.8.0-1024-raspi 

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/scripts/OLED/HMON$ sudo apt install python3-gpiozero
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-gpiozero is already the newest version (1.4.1-1.2).

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/scripts/OLED/HMON$ pip3 install gpiozero
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: gpiozero in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.4.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pip to install 1.6.2 from pypi.org

https://pypi.org/project/gpiozero/

`pip install --force-reinstall gpiozero`

I don't know how that will play with your existing install.

Comment: great. I used your command and it worked (needed a reboot)